# Serve multiple Swagger UIs on different URLs with single C# ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I need to serve multiple swagger UIs on single C# ASP.NET Core application. This is needed because application API consists of internal "private" API for UI and other stuff and "public" API that can be accessed by other applications and users.

Each Swagger endpoint should be on it's own swagger UI page and have a different URL address. I am able to divide existing API specification to two different json files and the json files in different routes using this code on `Startup.cs` `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{ 
    ...

    app.UseSwagger()
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v0.1_public/swagger.json",  "Public API v0.1");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v0.1_private/swagger.json", "Private API v0.1");
            });
    ...
}
```

I divide the specifications by filtering and adding two Swagger generators in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...
     services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.DocumentFilter<PublicAPISwaggerFilter>();
            c.SwaggerDoc("v0.1_public", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "Public API",
                Version = "v0.1"
            });
        });
     services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.DocumentFilter<PrivateApiSwaggerFilter>();
            c.SwaggerDoc("v0.1_private", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "Private API",
                Version = "v0.1"
            });
        });
     ...
}
```

Swagger UI is then served on `https://localhost:port/swagger` and both endpoints are listed on dropdown menu.

How can I create two swagger UIs when other is on route `https://locahost:port/private/swagger` and other one is `https://locahost:port/public/swagger` and each one them is displaying only one of the endpoints described above?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I have the same question

Answer (score 2):

you can place your private and public controllers in separate directories (i.e Controllers/Private and Controllers/Public) and use controller model convention

1. Create controller conventions

```cs
public sealed class SwaggerConventions : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        // private controllers will contain 'private' word in namespace
        bool isPrivate = controller.ControllerType.Namespace != null && controller.ControllerType.Namespace.Contains("Private");

        controller.ApiExplorer.GroupName = isPrivate ? "private" : "public;
    }
}
```

2. Use conventions in your startup/program.cs

```
    builder.AddControllers(c =>
    {
        c.Conventions.Add(new SwaggerConentions());
    })
```

3. Configure swagger endpoints

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
    swagger.SwaggerDoc("public", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "public API", Version = "v1" });
    swagger.SwaggerDoc("private", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "private API", Version = "v1" });

}

app
.UseSwagger()
.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/public/swagger.json", "Public API V1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/private/swagger.json", "Private API");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call UseSwaggerUI multiple times with different settings. Make sure you use a different RoutePrefix so you can reach both of them.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{ 
    ...

    app.UseSwagger()
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v0.1_public/swagger.json",  "Public API v0.1");
                c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
            });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v0.1_private/swagger.json",  "Private API v0.1");
                c.RoutePrefix = "swagger-private";
            });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You will need to split out your private and public controllers into separate applications. Doing so is also beneficial as you don't want to mix publicly accessibly API's with internal ones. It will be easier to maintain this way.

If its the specific URL convention you are after this can be handled by IIS or other tools you are using to host the applications.